# custom useragent for platform ios in nativescript

Tags: ios, webview, nativescript

I use `webview.android.getSettings().setUserAgentString` to custom `useragent` to platform `android` but I don't know how to set `useragent` to platform `ios` in nativescript.

Comment: Try using this [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-webview-utils#setuseragent)

Comment: its not working, webview not show